# mysql ...in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
                cat.CategoryID as CategoryID,
                count(p.ProductID) as CountProducts
            FROM 
                Category as cat
                LEFT JOIN Products as p on p.CategoryID IN 
                       (SELECT CategoryID FROM Category as cd 
                           WHERE cd.ParrentCategoryID = '876')
            WHERE 
                CategoryID = '876'
            ORDER by Name
```

We are get error - "Column 'CategoryID' in where clause is ambiguous".

Tell me plese how will be right?

Comment: CategoryID is in both tables. It's not a good idea to name the identifier column with the name of the table - just `id` is the industry standard, because it works best.

Comment: The use of the `IN (subquery)` predicate in the `ON` clause is very odd. Normally, the predicates in the `ON` clause reference columns from tables in the FROM clause. (I'm having difficulty comprehending what the desired resultset actually is.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error you get tells you that the column `CategoryID` in your `WHERE` clause is ambiguous, that means that the system has a problem to identify the appropriate column because there are multiple `CategoryID` columns.

In order to fix this problem, use the alias to specify which column you want to use for your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT cat2.CategoryID AS CategoryID
    ,cat2.Name AS CategoryName
    ,COUNT(p.ProductID) AS CountProducts
FROM Category AS cat
INNER JOIN Category AS cat2 ON cat2.ParrentCategoryID = cat.CategoryID
INNER JOIN Products AS p ON p.CategoryID = cat2.CategoryID
WHERE cat.CategoryID = '876'
GROUP BY cat2.CategoryID, cat2.Name
ORDER BY cat2.Name
```

I also changed a bit the query to get the same result but instead of using a combination of `LEFT JOIN` + `IN` clause + sub query, i used `INNER JOIN` clauses.
With this query you only need to define your desired `CategoryID` once and it will automatically get every child categories.

I'm not sure that your query runs correctly because you're using the `COUNT` function without grouping the results by `CategoryID`...

Hope this will help you.

Comment: +1. This is the more usual pattern for a query; predicates in the ON clause reference columns of tables in the FROM clause (vs an `IN (subquery)` as in the OP query.

Comment: oh, im sorry for this - long night and i dont see small error (= sorry +1 for help and new knowledge

Comment: @learner Happy if you've learn something from that, the small errors are part of the developer's life ;-) Don't forget to mark one of the answers as "accepted" in order to close the question

Answer (score 4):

The "ambiguous column" error means that there's a reference to a column identifier, and MySQL has two (or more) possible columns that match the specification.

In this specific case, it's the reference to `CategoryID` column in the `WHERE` clause.

It's "ambiguous" whether `CategoryID` is meant to refer to the `CategoryID` column from `cat`, or refer to the `CategoryID` column from `p`.

The fix is to *qualify* the column reference with the table alias to remove the ambiguity. That is, in place of `CategoryID`, specify either `cat.CategoryID` or `p.CategoryID`.

---

Some additional notes:

It's very odd to have an `IN (subquery)` predicate in the `ON` clause. If `CategoryID` is not guaranteed to be unique in the `Category` table, this query would likely generate more rows than would be expected.

The normal pattern for a query like this would be something akin to:

```
SELECT cat.CategoryID     AS CategoryID
     , COUNT(p.ProductID) AS CountProducts
  FROM Category cat
  LEFT 
  JOIN Products p
    ON p.CategoryID = cat.CategoryID 
 WHERE cat.ParrentCategoryID = '876'
 ORDER BY cat.Name
```

Normally, the join predicates in the `ON` clause reference columns in two (or more) tables in the FROM clause. (That's not a SQL requirement. That's just the usual pattern.)

The predicate in the `ON` clause of the query above specifies that the value of the `CategoryID` column from the `cat` (Category) table *match* the value in the `CategoryID` column from the `p` (Product) table.

Also, best practice is to qualify **all** columns referenced in a query with the name of the table, or a table alias, even if the column names are not ambiguous. For example, the `Name` column in the `ORDER BY` clause.

One big benefit of this is that if (at some time in the future) a column named `Name` is added to the `Products` table, the query with an unqualified reference to `Name` would (then) begin to throw an "ambiguous column" error for the that reference. So, qualifying all column names avoids a working query "breaking" when new columns are added to existing tables.

Another big benefit is that to the reader of the statement. MySQL can very quickly look in the dictionary, to find which table `Name` is in. But readers of the SQL statement (like myself) who do not "know" which table contains the column named `Name`, would also need to look at the table definitions to find out. If the name were qualified, we would already "know" which table that column was from.

Comment: sorry for bad question - long night... +1 for help

Comment: Appreciated the simplicity of stating that the solution is to specify the table using table.column syntax!

Answer (score 2):

Try `WHERE cat.CategoryID = '876'`